# Tomcat Servlet and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, servlets, xampp

I am using XAMPP on windows 8. What i want to do is to access a MySQL Database from a Servlet.

I have included MySQL Connector J jar file to the /xampp/tomcat/lib directory and below is my code that i want to compile and run

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;

public class Exercise7 extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title>Servlet - MySQL</title></head>");
    out.println("<body>");

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");

        if (rs.next()) {
            out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        /*Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);*/
        out.println("Can't connect");

    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            /*Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);*/
            out.println("Can't connect");
        }
    }
    out.println("</body></html>");
}
}
```

When i access the page I see "can't connect" as result and that clearly means that there is a problem with connection between servlet and mysql, so can anyone help me with this.

Comment: *I know there are some more steps that i need to do but i am not getting it, so please can anyone help with very detailed steps here* you should ask about which specific steps you have problems instead of asking for almost a tutorial about creating web applications using Java. IMO start learning how to create a basic Java web application using JSP and servlets **only**, then add the database conectivity functionality over it, otherwise you will mix lot of concepts and possibly not grasping the ideas behind them.

Comment: buddy i am asking about detailed steps only on how to make a servlet connect to mysql

Comment: i am not asking for a web application ok and i think my question here must be telling you that i know what is a servlet and jsp and how to create, compile and run them

Comment: Then execute the code in a Java web application. If you have any specific problem, then ask about it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - I have edited my question please check if it suits your helping terms

Comment: @code You said your app keeps on saying _Can't connect_. Can you add `ex.printStackTrace()` in your catch block and add the stacktrace in your post.

Comment: Now you have a specific problem that we can help you to solve :). When handling exceptions you **must not** write a custom message only, it is better to also log the exception stacktrace that will explain the current error and probably how to fix it.

Comment: @Smit here is the stack trace java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

Comment: Move the MySQL database connection jar to WEB-INF/lib and try again.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thankyou very much for that tip friend i will follow it, however in on of my comments here i have included the actual stack trace

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza nope it's not helping and the same problem persists

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The connector jar is named as mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar

Comment: Looks like you haven't loaded the class from the driver. This should be like: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`, add this line before `con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Nope my friend still same

Comment: After adding `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`, did you get the same exception message in the stacktrace? Also, are you just modifying the code on the fly or recompiling the war and redeploying the web application?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes the same after adding that. I modify, compile, copy class file at proper place and then restart the server again and then access the servlet

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

Copied MySQL connector J jar file to "javaDirectory/jre/lib/ext" and the above code worked just fine

However there are other possible solutions and probably better than this one but for practice atleast this is good, i think so.